# FB App Open Graph - app doesn't post to the wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I am trying to make work the Open Graph. In the administration of the app I have these 2 items:

```
Action Types: write - note
Object Types: note
```

I don't know why, but Open Graph still doesn't work. I followed [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/) tutorial, but when I press the button, still getting **Error occured**.

Relevant code:

```
     <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# my_url: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/my_url#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="ID" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="note" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://google.com" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample text" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  function postCook()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/my_url:write',
        'post',
        { note: 'http://google.com' },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
</script>
```

```
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'ID', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
          });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
          var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
          d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));
    </script>

    <form>
      <input type="button" value="Write" onclick="postCook()" />
    </form>
```

I am playing with setup of Open Graph whole day, but still cannot find the right configuration.

Missing I something important? Or how could I debug deeply this basic application?

**EDIT** The error message says:

```
code: 2500
message: "Unknown path components: /my_url:write"
type: "OAuthException"
```

Also, when I open the link (from Facebook developer administration), where should be displayed all actions, there is just:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Comment: Log the response object to your browser’s JS console via `console.log(response)`, to see what the actual error _is_ …

Comment: Thanks, I added to the original post the error message.

Comment: And `my_url` is actually what exactly in your code?

Comment: No, there is obviously the correct URL name of the app.

Comment: So it is your app namespace, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. The weirdest thing is, that the array called "data" is still empty...

Comment: That’s not “weird” – if you haven’t managed to publish an action successfully yet, then there is no data to show for that query.

Comment: But then - how I can test my own action, if this action isn't listed? The error says, that the action I am trying to test doesn't exist..

Comment: In the detailed settings panel for your action in the app settings, check the section “advanced” at the very bottom – what does it say there for _Graph API URL_?

Comment: it says **graph.facebook.com/me/my_url:write**